# Keep prompting in loop on false if condition

Tags: javascript

I am making a program where teachers input a student's name and grades corresponding to a certain number of assignments (the teacher specifies the assignment).

I want to make it so that it has to be a number value for the grades that are inputted. So, I've added this code:

```
for (var g = 1; g <= assignments; g++) {
     var grade = prompt("Please enter the student score for assignment" + g + ".");
     if(typeof grade === 'number' && Math.Round(grade) % 1 == 0) {
             return true;
         } 
     else{ 
             var grade = prompt("Please enter the student score for assignment" + g + ".");

         }

         var gradecolumn = document.createElement("td");
         var gradetext = document.createTextNode(grade);
         gradecolumn.appendChild(gradetext);
         rowtwo.appendChild(gradecolumn);
    }
```

I have this down... but I want to make it so it will **continue to prompt until user inputs a valid data type.**

Another problem I have is I want to add the grades together **After they have been entered** and calculate a cumulative grade to assign a letter grade on certain grading scale... I know I'm going to assign the letter grades via a multiconditional if/else if statement. But I'm not sure how to call the grades after they've been entered, and how to add them together so I can input that result into the multiconditional part.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.. Also, should I be using parseInt for any of this?

Comment: something (any integer) modulo 1 is always 0

Comment: Throw the prompt into a while loop and while your conditions are false, prompt again.

Comment: maybe if(parseInt(grade)) ... instead of if(typeof grade === 'number' && Math.Round(grade) % 1 == 0) can do the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var range = {"A": 100, "B": 75, "C": 50, "D": 30, "E": 20, "F": 10}, score = 0;
for (var g = 1; g <= 3; g++) {
    var grade = undefined, letter = '';
    while (!grade) {
        var grade = prompt("Please enter the student score for assignment" + g + ".");
        if (parseInt(grade)) {
            // accumulate score
            score += parseInt(grade);
        }
        // grade is not a number
        else grade = undefined;
    }
}
// check for mark
for (key in range) {
    if (score<range[key]) letter = key;
}

if (!letter) alert("score "+score+" is out of range!");
else {
    alert(letter); // now you have it
}
```

demo also updated: http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/jNg2m/2/

Comment: perhaps you did not mean to create a global variable in the second line

Comment: I want to make it cumulative... so if the teacher says there's 6 assignments, he/she inputs 6 different values. At the end of that, I want to average all of those values together, THEN assign a letter.

Comment: so score += parseInt(grade); is what accumulates it? How can I divide that by the number of assignments there are? Say in the loop I have g <= assignments (a variable that's already defined)... how can I add the assignments variable to be divided into the result of the score accumulated?

Comment: i'm not sure, that i understand what you mean, but you can try to define score = [] in first line, and change accumulation to score[g] += parseInt(grade)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var g = 1;
var assignments = 5;
var done = false;
var grade, gradecolumn, gradetext;

while (!done)
{
    grade = prompt("Please enter the student score for assignment " + g + ".");
    if((grade+'').search(/^[0-9]{1,3}$/) > -1) 
    {
        gradecolumn = document.createElement("td");
        gradetext = document.createTextNode(grade);
         gradecolumn.appendChild(gradetext);
         rowtwo.appendChild(gradecolumn);

         // increment the counter
         g++;
         if (g > assignments)
         {
            done = true;
         }
    }
    else
    {
        alert('Please enter a valid score for assignment '+g+'.');
    }
}
```